# Integrating Raspberry Pi Camera with Qt application

Tags: qt, camera, embedded-linux, raspberry-pi

I am making a hobby project of digital still camera based on Raspberry Pi using Qt.

I have cross compiled Qt on Pi and able to successfully run a normal test Qt application on Pi.
Also the raspistill and raspivid utilities are running successfully.

The issue is with integrating the Rasp Pi camera. Before buying it I din’t knew that it does not support v4l2.

I want to show a live view of camera in the Qt application and capture the image when a Button is clicked.

What are the options except v4l2, for getting the live feed from camera in Qt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Raspberry Pi Camera can now be used with Video4Linux2.

Installation instructions and use case examples can be found at [Linux Projects](http://www.linux-projects.org/modules/sections/index.php?op=viewarticle&artid=14)